# bar-cobar or cobar-bar

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, adjoint-functors

What is the standard or best reference for the adjointnes of bar and cobar constructions?

Comment: ... are you wanting to update the nLab entry? or is it something else?

Comment: ahem, [nlab entry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bar+and+cobar+construction)

Comment: I am guessing this is a reference request, perhaps the citations at the bottom are what Dr. Stasheff is looking for. I would think that this was known before those papers, but I am not confident.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm telling you this, but I think that Husemoller-Moore-Stasheff is a good reference...

Comment: @Sean Tilson I have added a reference-request tag